# What's the shortest TSQL to concatenate a person's name which may contain nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

3 fields: FirstName, MiddleName, LastName

Any field can be null, but I don't want extra spaces. Format should be "First Middle Last", "First Last", "Last", etc.

Comment: I think the question should specify *inline* SQL. Otherwise you can just do a one character proc, as one of the answers mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a UDF:

```
`Select udfConcatName(First, Middle, Last) from foo`
```

That way all your logic for concatenating names is in one place and once you've gotten it written it's short to call.

Comment: Unless you make it an "inline" udf, this will adversely affect performance, as udfs (except the inline kind) get recompiled on evcery execution.   So they're fine for one time use, in a single row select. or to populate a variable b4 a multiple row select, but not on each row of a multiRow select

Comment: Good grief. Agreed. This will be as slow as molasses if you have to do it with any great number of values.

Answer (score 10):

```
    LTRIM(RTRIM(
    LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(FirstName, ''))) + ' ' + 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(MiddleName, ''))) + ' ' + 
    LTRIM(ISNULL(LastName, ''))
    ))
```

NOTE: This won't leave trailing or leading spaces. That's why it's a little bit uglier than other solutions.

Comment: I'd be curious to know (seriously!) why this is unhelpful... Perhaps the downvoter can enlighten me? It actually works exactly as requested and covers all corner cases.

Comment: Andrew, I really hate when this happens. Please vote on uservoice for a change: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/41056

Comment: Yeah. Considering the other two solutions don't actually do what is requested... Ah well, guess it's just sour grapes on my part. I would like to see some accountability though :(

Comment: Doesn't it leave a double space in the middle when there's no MiddleName? Probably needs a space-reduction substitution around the whole thing. Or something.

Comment: Hi Andrew,
Interestingly, yours wasn't the answer I down-voted! An earlier revision of Charles Bretana's answer was the one I downvoted (he used TRIM, which isn't a recognised TSQL function - see my comments to his post!). A SO bug perhaps? Anyway, I've removed the incorrect downvote on your answer.

Comment: You can use this to fix the problem with a null middle name: 
`ltrim(rtrim(isnull(' ' + MiddleName + ' ',' ')))` 
if MiddleName is null, the first portion of the `isnull` will evaluate to null, so you will get just a single space instead of a double space between the First & Last names.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming by "extra spaces", you mean extra spaces inserted during the concatenation (which is a reasonable assumption, I think. If you have extra spaces in your data, you should clean it up):

```
ISNULL(FirstName + ' ', '')  + ISNULL(MiddleName + ' ', '') + ISNULL(LastName, '')
```

works, since you'll add a space to the name - which if it's NULL yields NULL - which yields empty string.

Edit: If you don't count the SET OPTION - which can be a connection or db option:

```
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF
LTRIM(FirstName + ' ' + NULLIF(MiddleName + ' ', ' ') + LastName)
```

is a tiny bit shorter, but a large bit uglier.

Edit2: Since you accepted the UDF answer - IMO, that's a bit of a cheat - here's some in the same vein:

```
SELECT a FROM b
```

b is a view. ;) Or. a stored proc,

```
EXEC c
```

But, since EXEC is optional:

```
c
```

Comment: I selected the UDF because is was the shortest practical solution.I would probably use your (pre-edit) solution over a UDF, so I gave you an up vote.

Comment: +1 This is the best/shortest answer and fully meets the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 3):

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(FirstName, '') + ' ' + LTRIM(ISNULL(MiddleName, '') + ' ' + 
    ISNULL(LastName, ''))))
```

Comment: Note that this will leave extra spaces between the middle name and the last name (if the middle name has spaces on the end), and also after the last name (if it has spaces on the end).

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a computed column on the table that performs the concat for you using your preferred syntax from the many posted here? Then you will just query the computed column - very elegant and if you persist the computed column then you may even get slight performance increase.
[Example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
replace(ltrim(rtrim(isnull(FirstName, '') + ' ' + isnull(MiddleName, '') + ' ' + isnull(LastName, ''))), '  ', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

`LTrim(RTrim(Replace(IsNull(Firstname + ' ', '') + 
    isNull(MiddleName, '')  + 
    IsNull(' ' + LastName, ''), '  ', ' ')))`

Comment: TRIM is not a recognised built-in function name in TSQL

Comment: ahh, sorry, should have writen Ltrim(rtrim(...))

Answer (score 0):

```
'"' + ltrim(rtrim(isnull(FirstName,''))) + ' ' + ltrim(rtrim(isnull(MiddleName,''))) + 
' ' + ltrim(rtrim(isnull(LastName,''))) + '","' + ltrim(rtrim(isnull(FirstName,''))) + 
' ' + ltrim(rtrim(isnull(LastName,''))) + '","' + ltrim(rtrim(isnull(LastName,''))) + 
'"'
```

ETC

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @first varchar(10) = 'First'
DECLARE @middle varchar(10) = ''
DECLARE @last varchar(10) = 'Last'

LTRIM(RTRIM(
    @first
    + ISNULL(NULLIF(' '+LTRIM(RTRIM(@middle)),' '),'')
    + ISNULL(NULLIF(' '+LTRIM(RTRIM(@last)),' '),'')
))
```

WHY THIS WORKS

The fields are reduced to an empty string if NULL or whitespace by the LTRIM, RTRIM, and ISNULL functions.

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(@middle,''))) -- Result is a trimmed non-null string value.
```

That value is prefixed with a single space, then compared to a single space by the NULLIF function.  If equal, a NULL results.  If not equal, then the value is used.

```
NULLIF(' '+'',' ')       -- this would return NULL
NULLIF(' '+'Smith',' ')  -- this would return ' Smith'
```

Finally, ISNULL() is used to convert the NULL passed by NULLIF to an empty string.

```
ISNULL(NULL,'')          -- this would return ''
ISNULL(' Smith','')      -- this would return ' Smith'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select firstname, middlename, lastname, ProvidedName = 

RTrim(Coalesce(FirstName + ' ','') 
+ Coalesce(MiddleName + ' ', '')
+ Coalesce(LastName + ' ', '')
+ COALESCE('' + ' ', '')
+ COALESCE(NULL, ''))

From names
```